# Aggregate and $lookup by $project field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to aggregate on my User collection and `$project` out the fields I need. Then I want to set let variables in `$lookup` to be able to use the variable to find matching documents.

I want to do it this way, because I will have many `$lookups` by the variables.

However I am not able to get this working correctly. What am I doing wrong with the variables?

```
$project: {
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        goal: 1
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "goals",
        let: { user: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    "user": "$$user"
                }
            },
            { $project: { _id: 0, leads: 0 } },
        ],
        as: "goal"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        goal: 1
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$expr` to use variable name inside the `$match` stage.

```
{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$user', '$$user'] }}}
```